# Present ViewController modally from UITabBarController without hiding the tab bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with 5 items in it. I have also a side menu with couple of items. When tapping one of the items in the side menu I need to present view controller modally without hiding the tab bar. I tried the following:

1. Presenting it from the `selectedViewController`

   ```
    tabBarController.selectedViewController?.present(contactsViewController, animated: false, completion: {})
   ```
2. Presenting it from the `UITabBarController` itself

   ```
   tabBarController.present(contactsViewController, animated: true) {}
   ```
3. Adding a `modal segue` in Storyboard from the selectedViewController to the contactsViewController and performing it

All of these led to the tabBar being hidden. Is it possible to present the view controller modally without hiding the tab bar and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` methods to present menu modally.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
    {
        if tabBarVC?.tabBar.selectedItem?.tag == 5
        {
            tabBarVC?.present(SideMenuManager.default.menuRightNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```